# Active and Inactive DIVs using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a color palette:

css

```
.colors {width:75px;height:75px;background-color:red;border:1px solid #000;}
.highlight {width:75px;height:75px;background-color:red;border:2px solid #000;}
```

html

```
<div class="colors">Red</div>
<div class="colors">blue</div>
<div class="colors">green</div>
```

the user supposed to choose what color he want,
so I want the border of the the color chosen by the user to be 2px;

```
$("div").click(function () {
  $(this).toggleClass("highlight");
});
```

this is work fine, but when i click on anothe color the old color still actived and when i click on the same color becomes inactive and i don't want that.

what i want is:

1. border change when active.
2. if i click on another one the old one becomes inactive.
3. when i click on the active one again I dono't want something to happen i want it as it was actived.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want would look like this:

```
$("div").click(function () {
  $(this).addClass("highlight").siblings().removeClass("highlight");
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/P2rz4/).  What this does is just add the class on click (not toggle it so it can come off) via [`.addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) then those [`.siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/)get the class removed via [`.removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).

---

If your example is off and they're not siblings, just use [`.removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) on the same selector as your [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) handler before adding it to the clicked element, like this:

```
$("div").click(function () {
  $("div").removeClass("highlight");
  $(this).addClass("highlight");
});
```